# Setting Width and Height to Loader

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am using the code below to loop grab the variables from my `xml` file.
My `xml` file contains an image path (http://www.mydomain.com/images/image.jpg) but the width and height is a little bit large.

When i am setting up `.width` and `.height` to currentLoader my thumbs stops appearing.

I tried the `.scaleY` and `.scaleX` but all my thumbs dont have the same `width`and `height`.

Is it possible someone to help me to solve this?

```
private function xmlLoaded(evt:Event):void
{

var currentPosY:Number = 0;
imagesXML = new XML(evt.target.data);
for (var i:uint = 0; i < imagesXML.article.length(); i++)
{

listItem=new itemList();
listItem.x = 25;
listItem.y = currentPosY;
listItem.num=i;
listContainer.loaderMc.addChild(listItem);
currentPosY +=  125;
trace(imagesXML.article[i].photo.toString());
listItem.labelTxt.text = imagesXML.article[i].name.toString();
loadThumbsFromXml(listItem,imagesXML.article[i].photo.toString());
listItem.buttonMode=true;
listItem.mouseChildren=false;
listItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,openPreview);

}

boundsScroll = new flash.geom.Rectangle(480,0,0,455);
setScroll();

}


private function loadThumbsFromXml(target:MovieClip,path:String)
 {          
var currentLoader:Loader=new Loader();
currentLoader.load(new URLRequest(path));           
//currentLoader.width = 115;
//currentLoader.height = 95;
target.thumbLoader.addChild(currentLoader);

}
```

Comment: The solution is in this my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674991/movieclip-disappear-after-changing-width-and-height-in-as3/14675131#14675131

Comment: @fsbmain You can actually do it before the COMPLETE event fires. You have full access to content properties after the INIT event fires. In fact, I believe Adobe recommends listening for the INIT even rather than the COMPLETE event because it could screw with your layout if you wait to set it until COMPLETE (which will fire who knows when)

Answer (score 0):

I see you found an answer for your question .... but i have another way to get it  so my way is to creat in your library a new symbol as MovieClip and linkage it as Mc_Holder ... the point is :  the MovieClip you added have a Square (or any thing you want ) in it and the flash have knowledge about it's properties of it befor you add Child of your loader so you have the width and hieght now ;)

my code

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var url:String = "images/1.jpg";
var myloader:Loader = new Loader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var mc_holder:Sprite = new Mc_Holder();  // from library 
addChild (mc_holder);

myloader.load(request);
mc_holder.addChild(myloader);

mc_holder.width =10;
mc_holder.height =10;
```

actually it is Not your "Loader width and hieght"  but you can scale it and put a new one as you want depend on width and hieght Mc_Holder