# actionscript loader set size image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Im trying to load an image to my swf by actionscript. I tried code like below:

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();


    myLoader.x = 250;
    myLoader.y = 0;



    myLoader.load(new URLRequest("z.jpg"));


    addChild(myLoader);
```

It works well but i need set the all images i load in same size. As many sites i searched i found something code below:

```
myLoader.height=40;
myLoader.width=40;
```

But when i add this code my image dissapears. what is the problem and how can i fix it?
thanks for help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674991/movieclip-disappear-after-changing-width-and-height-in-as3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674991/movieclip-disappear-after-changing-width-and-height-in-as3?lq=1). Read his/her question and then the first answer.